# Keeping track of already seen objects

Tags: java, object

I'm trying to implement an interceptor for my application, that would be able to keep track of objects it has seen. I need to be able to tell, whether the object I'm seeing now is something new, or a reused one.

Assuming I have an interface like this one:

```
public interface Interceptor {
    void process(Object o);
}
```

I've been thinking about adding a Set that would keep track of those objects. But since I don't want to cause memory leaks with that kind of behavior, perhaps I should devise some other pattern? In the end, those objects may be destroyed in other layers.

Possible solutions seem:

- putting hashCode of an object into the Set
- using WeakHashSet instead of HashSet

the first option seems not 100% reliable, because hashCode may not be unique. As for the second option, I'm not that sure this will prevent memleaks.

And one more note, I'm not able to modify the objects, I can't add fields, methods. Wrapping is also not an option.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`WeakReferences` are the way to go. From [here](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2006/05/04/understanding-weak-references):

> A weak reference, simply put, is a reference that isn't strong enough
>   to force an object to remain in memory. Weak references allow you to
>   leverage the garbage collector's ability to determine reachability for
>   you, so you don't have to do it yourself.

i.e. keeping a `WeakReference` won't force the JVM to hold a reference to this object.

> Of course the weak reference isn't strong enough to prevent garbage
>   collection, so you may find (if there are no strong references to the
>   widget) that weakWidget.get() suddenly starts returning null.

Comment: See above. The get() method will give you a null

Answer (score 1):

Just a completion to Brian Agnew correct answer. There is no `WeakHashSet` class in java API, you'll need to create it from a `WeakHashMap` like this:

```
Set<Object> weakHashSet = Collections.newSetFromMap(
        new WeakHashMap<Object, Boolean>());
```

See [Collections.newSetFromMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#newSetFromMap%28java.util.Map%29) java docs.